# How to embed C OpenGL application in C# GUI?

Tags: c#, c, opengl, user-interface, embed

I have 3D OpenGL application written in C for Unix-like systems, it is working fine in Linux, but lacks GUI and is only controllable via keyboard.
As far as I know C# GUI is the simplest and nicest and cutest to create and it's very easy to create nice gui in C# in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

SO I decided I want to embed graphical application written in C OpenGL in C# application GUI, just something like this:
http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/2773/qoyz.jpg

Of course I want to control C application from my C# GUI.
It could be done any possible way I was thinking maybe about some dll file compiled from C OpenGL code?

I dont have any experience with that kind of stuff, so give me clear answers:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably going to need to create a managed code wrapper for your C project so that it can be accessed from C#.

See this previously asked question: [Porting (unmanaged) C++ to C# vs. using the C++ as a DLL in a C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167028/porting-unmanaged-c-to-c-sharp-vs-using-the-c-as-a-dll-in-a-c-sharp-appli)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Qt SDK](http://qt-project.org/search/tag/qt~sdk)?  With it you can create not less "cutest, nicest " GUI which is also c++ and cross platform, contrary to MS WinForms or WPF. In fact,many GUI based programs, like Maya or Aftereffects, use Qt

Comment: I run MS WinForms even on Linux using Mono framework, indeed it portable on all system supported by Mono.

Comment: If you don't care about performance that's fine.Wrappers impact performance so wrapping OpenGL with C# is not the best performance wise idea...

Comment: Surely P/Invoking cost more, but the performance equation includes the number of calls also; unless you send 10K vertices using deprecated functionalities nobody will notice. That's my experience.